# Replicate a database using snapshots and transaction logs

Tags: database, database-replication, transactional-replication

For learning purposes, I want to write my own database, that is able to replicate itself. I have made some progress, but now I am facing a problem that I can not solve. Supposed I have a database (let's call this source) that I would like to replicate to another database (let's call this target).

The basic principle is easy: In the source you don't store actual tables, but instead a log of transactions. It's easy to send over the transaction log to the target, where the database then rebuilds itself. If you want to update the target, you simply request the part of the transaction log that has changed ever since. Basically this is what almost every database does.

While this works, it has one major drawback: If a table already exists for a long time, the transaction log is very long, and hence replicating the table requires lots of time…

To avoid this you can store the current state as well. This means you have an up-to-date snapshot that you can copy fast. Additionally, the target has to subscribe to the transaction log of the source. Once it contains additional entries, the target applies them to its copied table. This works well, too, and it's way better in terms of performance and transferred volume.

But now I am facing a problem: Supposed the snapshot is large, then it may happen that changes are made to it while it is being delivered. That means that the copied snapshot contains some old and some new data. Now, how do I get the target database in a consistent state? Even if I know from where to start the transaction log, I either have to apply a change that was already applied to some of the records, or I have to leave it out, but then a change is not applied at all to some other records.

Of course I could use the isolation level sequential, but then performance drops. Of course I could do what e.g. CouchDB does and remember the current table revision in every record, and keep a copy of every record for every revision. But then the required space grows enormously.

So, what shall I do?

Everything that I was able to find on the web always either relies on the idea of replaying the entire transaction log, or by using a process as in CouchDB which takes up huge amounts of space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snapshot needs to be consistent and you need to know at what time (in regards to the tx log) it is consistent. You then apply any transactions that have been committed since this point.

Obtaining a consistent snapshot can be done with exclusive locking, which may delay other transactions from committing, or using row versions (MVCC).

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with MVCC, that was helpful :-)